# iOS 9 VoiceOver reading table out of order when focusing on a column

Tags: javascript, ios, voiceover

VoiceOver is reading my table columns out of order. For example, I'll select the column that reads "Date", it'll first read a column 3 rows below, "Comment" and then "Date." My table layout is a basic layout:

```
<table>
   <caption></caption>
   <tbody>
      <tr><th>Date</th><td>{{u.date}}</td></tr>
      <tr><th>User</th><td>{{u.user}}</td></tr>
      <tr><th>ISR</th><td>{{u.ISR}}</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Comment</th><td>{{u.comment}}</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: Apparently this has been around since at least iOS 7. Take a look at this video, from 2:00 - 2:05. You can see when he selects 8:30PM it first reads 9:00PM.
https://youtu.be/mDonEpP4Ouw?t=122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this answer was to stay away from tables. Changed all to bootstrappable divs instead